# Count read lines when bulk insert

Tags: t-sql, bulkinsert

Is it possible to count lines which was read from import file ?

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2)  
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'F:\test.csv',  FORMATFILE='f:\test.XML',  ERRORFILE='F:\test.csv.log') AS a
WHERE col1%3=0;
```

Comment: You can use alternative this techique http://stackoverflow.com/q/11356911/1080354 for inserting records in tables - it shows the count of importing rows and many other import details.

Comment: I would like count stings in source file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) after your statement statement.