# Inserting multiple data into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am learning to use SQL Server 2008 R2, and I'm a little stuck at the INSERT option. I want to insert multiple data at once and I'm using this :

```
INSERT INTO Members (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)

VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'),

       ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'),

       ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5')
```

which ofc works. But let's say I have like a 1000 records that I want to insert (from another file, for e.g. Excel), how can I do that ? Any reference to where I can learn this ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [bulk importing data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937(v=sql.105).aspx)? `BULK INSERT`, `bcp.exe` and SSIS are all common solutions, depending on your requirements and preferences. There is a lot of information in the documentation and online about all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Use SELECT statement to insert multiple data like:

```
INSERT INTO Members (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
SELECT 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'
UNION
SELECT 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'
UNION
SELECT 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Members (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run a `Export Wizard` on the database. Just follow the below steps.

Step 1: Right Click on the Database
Step 2: Select Task
Step 3: Select Export Data
Step 4: Enter Data Source details   ( here you will select your Excel file )

- Select Excel File as DataSource
- And give the Excel file path

Step 5: Enter Destination details  ( your table name  )
Step 6: Select the tables you want to recreate.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you may save your data file to CSV format file, eg C:\myData.csv
2. Execute the statement " LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/myData.csv' INTO TABLE Members"

Hope this can help you:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want insert values from an excel file, use the import wizard of sql server, it's the easiest. In sql server, right-click your database, point to Tasks, and then click Import Data or Export data.
(look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx for more explaination)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

> The maximum number of rows that can be constructed by inserting rows
>   directly in the VALUES list is 1000. Error 10738 is returned if the
>   number of rows exceeds 1000 in that case. To insert more than 1000
>   rows, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Create multiple INSERT statements
> - Use a derived table
> - Bulk import the data by using the bcp utility or the BULK INSERT    statement

If you want to use the bcp utility this is a nice answer of how it is used : [SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - Export/Import data from/to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356911/sql-server-management-studio-2012-export-import-data-from-to-table)