# TSQL bulk insert without knowing the headers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please give me a hand on this challenge.

I want to import a big text file (>12gb). I was told that it has more than 600 columns. But I dont know if it has headers or not. I've tried notepad++, notepad, excel, and LTFViewr to see what the headers are but have had no success.
I tried import wizard but it shows only 2 columns, which is not correct.
I dont want to use SSIS to import this file because it's going to be very slow. I would like to import the file to sql server as fast as possible before processing further.

Is there a way to bulk insert in similar fashion as "SELECT * INTO ...."?

Thank you!

Comment: If the import wizard is guessing at 2 columns, what makes you think any other component wouldn't (by default) also guess at 2 columns?

Comment: You could try using a command prompt and the `more` command to display the first part of the file - it's probably the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356911/sql-server-management-studio-2012-export-import-data-from-to-table

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use BCP utility provided with SQL Server.